# AjaxControlToolKit Not Compatible with 64 bit Environment Under .Net 4

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Writing a web application for a Windows 2008 R2 64 bit server.

Visual Studio 2010, .Net Framework 4, 64 bit Windows 7 on 64 bit hardware. I create an ASP.NET Web Application, right click on the project, go to properties, under the build tab, set the platform target to x64.

I downloaded the Ajax .net 4 toolkit. In the Toolbox, I add a tab and to it, the AjaxControlToolkit.

I drop in an Ajax control from the Toolbox into my default page. eg: ToolkitScriptManager. The intellisense underlines it. The warning message is:

Element 'ToolkitScriptManager' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.

I have a web.config file, it's there by default and I don't normally mess with it.

i run the app and get the following error message:

Could not load file or assembly 'WebApplication1' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Switching the Target Platform back to Any CPU fixes this problem, but doesn't address it.